# Do i need to pay debt i loaned as a kid

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, debt

When i was a kid, about 10 years and didn't know about islam and about debt I was buying something and I didn't have enough money, I needed about 0.50$ so I asked to buy a thing and then I will give that money latter. Couple days ago I was reading something about debt and remembered that. Now since it was very long ago(about 10 years) I don't know if I payed that debt, maybe I am but I'm not sure. Because I came him after that couple years after that and he didn't mention anything. What should I do, does it matters because I was too young, and that guy, I don't know who he is and he's name, probably don't remember that? Money is not problem, but how to find guy now, and is he going to remember? PS. Sorry for bad english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

These conditions below would give you a pass on sins or islamic responsibilities,

1. You were not a muslim back then, 2. You were a child (did not reach puberty), 3. You had some cognitive deficiency, 4. You were ignorant of the rulings or responsibilty.

If you are really worried about that just ask Allah for repentance, he's the most merciful. And be sure to pay back your debts the next time you take a loan and dont deal in riba.